# memory management - interview question

Tags: memory-management, memory-allocation, resource-allocation

I was asked the following question in an interview and I don't understand what is the best solution for it -

Assume you have an application that needs memory. It asks for a program for this memory, 20 bytes each time.
Each allocation (calling to malloc) costs another 8 bytes, so actually, you use 28 bytes (if you allocate 100 bytes, so it costs you 108 bytes).
The memory can be freed later and then its address is available again.

You need to find a program to minimize the byte cost.

I thought to allocate 100 bytes at the beginning, then to use a variable to save the address and a counter to save the available bytes. Then at each allocation, insert the address to a HashSet (represents all the taken addresses), and increase the address variable by 20 and decrease the counter. But then if the taken address is freed I need to take it out of the Set (thought about another set). Eventually, I didn't save much memory in this solution(each variable and address takes 4 bytes).

I can't think of a better solution, I will be happy to hear any other suggestions,
Thank you

Comment: I suspect we're missing some context.  Minimize the byte cost for what?  I don't understand what the  problem is or what is happening in your proposed solution ("save the address and a counter" - what address?).

Comment: There is an app that needs memory, 20 bytes each time. It asks a program for an address of this memory block of 20 bytes. Each allocation costs 8 bytes. So instead of allocating 20 bytes each time, you can, for example, allocate 100 bytes (which costs you 108 bytes) and manage the addresses of the memory you allocated. But then you need to keep track of these addresses.

Comment: If you allocate 100 bytes and the application asks only for 20 bytes, you are not minimizing the byte cost.

Comment: It asks for 20 bytes many times

Comment: You seem to be asking how to write a [memory allocator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#DYNAMIC).  That sounds too broad to me.  There's an enormous amount written on this subject and I doubt it can be answered in a few paragraphs.  What research have you done?  I suggest doing some reading on that topic area.  Different memory allocators address different requirements or tradeoffs, e.g., how critical it is to avoid space overhead, fragmentation, or other issues; what allocation patterns one optimizes for; and so on.  That information is not provided in the question.